# dynamically creating window form according to data returned from dataset (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataset that returns questions and answers from the database, each answer in answer table is linked via a forgein key to the question table.

What I would like to achive is the following:

That a a single dynamic form is created on the first question with all the questions listed under it, meaning the FK_table_Answers = PK_table_Questions on the table_Answers:

(eg)  This is Form for Question One:

```
    Question One: How old are you?

   Answer One (this is a radio button)

   Answer Two (this is a radio button)

  Answer Three (this is a radio button)
```

I have managed to get the above kind of working but the problem is my code keeps generating the forms (eg) 3 times becuase there are three answers, so can anyone point me in right direction how to generate the form dynamically but only ONCE - meaning each successive form is created only once as per the question and that particular questions answers under it.

Kind regards

UPDATED code:

```
    private void LoadDataSets()
    {
        if (_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                //Questionnaire:
                DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireTableAdapter questionnaireAdapter =
                                 new DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireTableAdapter();
                questionnaireAdapter.Fill(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_Questionnaire);

                //Category:
                DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireCategoryTableAdapter categoryAdapter =
                               new DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireCategoryTableAdapter();
                categoryAdapter.Fill(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_QuestionnaireCategory);

                //QuestionnaireQuestion:
                DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestionTableAdapter questionnaireQuestionAdapter =
                                  new DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestionTableAdapter();
                questionnaireQuestionAdapter.Fill(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion);

                //QuestionnaieAnswer:
                DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireAnswerTableAdapter questionnaireAnswerAdapter =
                                 new DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireAnswerTableAdapter();
                questionnaireAnswerAdapter.Fill(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer);

                using (DataSet1 dSet = new DataSet1())
                {
                    //Questionnaire:
                    dSet.Merge(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_Questionnaire);
                    //Category:
                    dSet.Merge(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_QuestionnaireCategory);
                    //QuestionnaireQuestion:
                    dSet.Merge(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion);
                    //QuestionnaieAnswer:
                    dSet.Merge(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer);

                    int primaryKeyQuestionnaire = Convert.ToInt32(_dataSetQuestionnaire.tbl_Questionnaire.Rows[0][0]);

                    foreach (DataSet1.tbl_QuestionnaireRow questionnaire
                                        in _dataSetQuestionnaire.Tables["tbl_Questionnaire"].Select(String.Format("pk_tbl_Questionnaire = {0}", primaryKeyQuestionnaire)))
                    {
                        foreach (DataSet1.tbl_QuestionnaireCategoryRow category
                                       in _dataSetQuestionnaire.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireCategory"].Select(String.Format("fk_tbl_Questionnaire = {0}", questionnaire.pk_tbl_Questionnaire)))

                                       {
                            foreach (DataSet1.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestionRow question
                                           in _dataSetQuestionnaire.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion"].Select(String.Format("fk_tbl_QuestionnaireCategory = {0}", category.pk_tbl_QuestionnaireCategory)))
                            {
                                int radiobuttonPosition = 0;
                                foreach (DataSet1.tbl_QuestionnaireAnswerRow answer
                                                   in _dataSetQuestionnaire.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer"].Select(String.Format("fk_tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion = {0}", question.pk_tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion)))
                                {


                                    //Gets the questins via the FK_questionnaireQuestion and fill the _dataSetRadioButtons to generate on dynamic form.
                                    DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireAnswerTableAdapter a =
                                                     new DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_QuestionnaireAnswerTableAdapter();

                                    DataSet dSetRadioButtons = new DataSet();
                                    dSetRadioButtons.Merge(a.GetDataByQuestionnaireQuestion(answer.fk_tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion));
                                    _dataSetRadioButtons = dSetRadioButtons;

                                    string theQuestion = question.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion_Description.ToString();

                                    Form form = new Form();
                                    _form = form;

                                    if(_form == null)
                                    {
                                        _form = new Form();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        form.Height = 400;
                                        form.Width = 550;
                                        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

                                        Label label = new Label();
                                        label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 10);
                                        label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(450, 25);
                                        label.Text = theQuestion;

                                        Panel panel = new Panel();
                                        panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);
                                        panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 50);
                                        panel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                                        System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton[] radioButtons = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton[_dataSetRadioButtons.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer"].Rows.Count];

                                        for (int i = 0; i < _dataSetRadioButtons.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer"].Rows.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
                                            radioButtons[i].Text = _dataSetRadioButtons.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer"].Rows[i]["tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer_Description"].ToString();
                                            radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 20 + i * 20);

                                            //panel.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);

                                            radioButtons[i].Click += new EventHandler(Form1_Click);

                                            Int64 item = Convert.ToInt64(_dataSetRadioButtons.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer"].Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString());
                                            panel.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
                                        }

                                        Button nextButton = new Button();
                                        nextButton.Text = "Next";
                                        nextButton.Name = "button";
                                        nextButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 300);
                                        nextButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 25);
                                        nextButton.Click += new EventHandler(nextButton_Click);

                                        form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { panel, label, nextButton });

                                        form.ShowDialog();

                                        CreateBoxAndQuestion(form, panel, label);

                                        //form.Dispose();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }

    private void CreateBoxAndQuestion(Form f, Panel p, Label l)  
    {
        for (int i = p.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            p.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi guys sorry Im new to the forum how do I add the code to show u?

Comment: Clearly you want to query *only* table_Questions.  When you fill the form for a question, *then* query table_Anwsers.

Comment: Edit question, paste PART OF IMPORTANT code and pres ctrl+k to indent it.

Comment: oki added CreateBoxAndQuestion method for you to view

Comment: can you show code where you calling CreateBoxAndQuestion method?

Comment: Reniuz added the load dataset method as requested - I use the adapters to fill my datasets then merge them with the tbales and on the application xsd dataset do my queries to fill each dataset according to the PK's and FK's that i get back from my DB

Comment: I just noticed that you calling CreateBoxAndQuestion method when looping through answers, that's why you getting many forms for question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you call CreateBoxAndQuestion every time a new question is selected.
But you create (and destroy) the form each time your code enters in this method.
A first approach would be to keep the form, label, button and panel creation outside the method (perhaps in design mode) then passing these controls to the method as

EDIT: Somewhere in your code before entering the load of your next question:

```
frmQuestion _form = null; // Global

// Create a global instance and keep it without displaying
if(_form == null) _form = new frmQuestion(); // frmQuestion created with panel, label e button via FormDesigner
```

then when you need to populate _form call

```
CreateBoxAndQuestion(_form, _form.Panel, _form.Label, questionText);
```

In this example I pass the _form to CreateBoxAndQuestion, but this is not necessary because is a global. You could change CreateBoxAndQuestion to use directly the global instance.

```
private void CreateBoxAndQuestion(frmQuestion f, Panel p, Label l, string _label) 
{
    // Do not display your form here....
}
```

Now when entering the method clear every RadioButton controls in the panel.Controls collection

```
for (int i = p.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{ 
    p.Controls.RemoveAt(i); 
}
```

the rest of the code should change only to reflect the new text assigned to the label and controls and the re-adding of the RadioButtons to the panel. No more creation and reinitialization for Form Label, Button.

label.Text = _label;

Don't forget to destroy _form at the end of your program with _form.Dispose();

Comment: hi steve - will try your suggestion rite away fanx :)

Comment: steve could you eloborate please on how you mean "keep the form, label, button and panel creation outside the method (perhaps in design mode) then passing these controls to the method as"

Comment: steve sorry but I dont thin k I am grasping the concept the you are trying to suggest please se updated code

Comment: From what I have understood, you are preparing some kind of survey or poll application. If this is the case, I will separate data loading from the display of that data. I will create a form in FormDesigner with a combobox with datasource pointing to the tbl_Questionnaire, another one for the tbl_QuestionnaireCategory, and the last one for the tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion. Then I will let the user choose what Questionnaire, Category and Question wishes to see. I will handle the change in the selection and prepare the dynamic part of the form with the possible answers for the question selected.

Comment: you are 100% rite that its a polling application thnks steve will work on it :)